# joining a table on two columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

I have a companies table like this

```
====================
companyid, companyname
  2         com A
  3         com B
  4         com C
  5         com D
  6         com E
```

I ran a query where the resulting dataset looks like the following

```
====================================
name |  InvoiceTo_ID |   ProviderID 
------------------------------------
p1          2               3
p2          2               4
p3          6               3
p4          5               6
```

Now what I want is to join my dataset with the `companies` table above so that for `InvoiceTo_ID` I get a corressponding name and for `ProviderID` I get a corresponding name. Here is the final result

```
======================================================================
name |  InvoiceTo_ID |   ProviderID | InvoiceTo_Name |  ProviderName 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
p1          2               3               com A             com B
p2          2               4               com A             com C
p3          6               3               com E             com B
p4          5               6               com D             com E
```

How would I structure my joins so that it joins on both invoiceID and ProviderID WITHOUT creating duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to JOIN your query to the `companies` table twice to get the final result. One join will get the `InvoiceTo_Name` and the second join gets the `ProviderName`:

```
select q.name,
  q.InvoiceTo_ID,
  q.ProviderID,
  c1.companyname InvoiceTo_Name,
  c2.companyname ProviderName
from yourquery q
left join companies c1
  on q.InvoiceTo_ID = c1.companyid
left join companies c2
  on q.ProviderID = c2.companyid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1103/1).  This gives a result:

```
| NAME | INVOICETO_ID | PROVIDERID | INVOICETO_NAME | PROVIDERNAME |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   p1 |            2 |          3 |          com A |        com B |
|   p2 |            2 |          4 |          com A |        com C |
|   p3 |            6 |          3 |          com E |        com B |
|   p4 |            5 |          6 |          com D |        com E |
```